# lsyncd: big directories

Tags: rsync, inotify

My plan was to use lsyncd to synchronize a directory with about 1,5m files and 0,3m directories to another host. Performance is not most important.

After first tests I see that lsyncd uses inotify and that is limited my system-settings (e.g. max_user_watches).

Is there a way I can tell lsyncd to "take it easy" and not use an inotify-registration for every file/directory?

If I set my system-settings to the required values - do I need to be afraid of a slow-down or other negatives?